# Why value is vector 'c' is not getting updated in the loop?

Tags: r, loops, vector

I'm trying to print an updated value of the vector 'c' each time the value of 'coh' is changing. Although the value of 'coh' is changing, the value of 'c' is not. Can someone guide me where I am doing this wrong?

```
p <- filter(data, p_id == 1)
coh <- c(0.175, 0.250, 0.325)
i <- 1
for (x in coh){
  pc <- filter(p, coh_list == x)
  vec <- vector()
  while (i < 41){
    if (pc[i,"acc_list"] == 1  && pc[i+1,"acc_list"] == 1 ){
      dif <- ((pc[i, "rt_data"]) - (pc[i+1, "rt_data"]))
      vec <- c(vec, dif)
    }
    i <- i + 2
  }
  print(x)
  print(vec)
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
[1] 0.175
 [1]  0.121050 -0.653415 -0.046155  0.468270  0.241260  0.540885 -0.299720 -0.851900
 [9] -0.090035  0.088955
[1] 0.25
logical(0)
[1] 0.325
logical(0)
```

Comment: you had better use another name instead of `c`

Comment: `c` is the function concatenate.

Comment: Okay.I tried that, it doesn't makes any difference.

Comment: I think you just have to reset `i <- 1` WITHIN the `for` loop. Currently, i is reaching 41 ... and stay there. The code don't go in your `while` loop anymore.